# Lorentz Force Dimension Analysis

Tags: electromagnetism, units, dimensional-analysis

A charged particle in the presence of charges and currents experiences
a force due to electric (E) and magnetic (B) fields. Is
is described by the Lorentz force:

$$F = e (E  +  v × B )$$

where e is the charge of the particle and v is the instantaneous velocity of
the particle.

If we use the units of the International System and we do unit analysis. How can we conlcude that in the end its got units of force (Newton).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it shows no prior research

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we expand the relation we get.

$F$= $eE+evB$

Where $e$ = charge = $[M^0L^0T^1A^1]$

$E$ = Electric Field = $[M^1L^1T^{-3}A^{-1}]$

multiplying $eE$ = $[M^1L^1T^{-2}A^0]$ , which is the dimension of force.

Similarly,

v = velocity = $[M^0L^1T^{-1}A^0]$

B = Magnetic Field = $[M^1L^0T^{-2}A^{-1}]$

Multiplying $evB$ = $[M^1L^1T^{-2}A^0]$

Thus, we prove that the Lorentz force $F=e(E+vB)$ has the dimension $Newton(N)$.

Comment: This is correct, but shows the confusion introduced by SI.

Comment: What's the confusion can u elaborate?

Comment: does the cross product affect here?

Comment: Now I see sin(theta) is adimensional so we dont care

Comment: Giving charge a unit is one confusion if SI.

Comment: Giving charge a unit is one confusion of SI.  "In 1901 Giorgi showed that it is possible to combine the mechanical units of this MKS system with the practical electric units to form a coherent four-dimensional system by adding to the three base units a fourth unit, of an electrical nature such as the ampere or the ohm, and also rewriting the equations occurring in electromagnetism in the so-called rationalized form. Giorgi's proposal opened the path to a number of new developments."  Georgi didn't know about SR, QM, or much about physics. In  natural units, no derivation is necessary.

Comment: Another confusion of SI is giving E and B, parts of the same tensor, different units.  In Gaussian units, E and B have the same units, but even there, they are named after different people.
The problem is that the conventions are controlled by engineers, who don't care about modern physics.